# How to browserify a preloaded tree of files?

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify

I'm preloading my .js files into memory, so that it looks like this:

```
loadedDirectory = {
  fileName1: 'console.log("some js"); require("./subDirectory/fileName2");',
  subDirectory: {
    fileName2: 'console.log("some more");',
  },
};
```

My question is how can I pass an object like this so `browserify`, so that it will not touch the disk ( as I already loaded everything )?

Comment: I'd like to run it through the `browserify` node module, and eventually pipe to a string the result of `.bundle()`.